# Is Chrome OS supposed to restart on login screen?

Tags: chrome, chrome-os, chrome-book, google

Is Chrome OS supposed to restart if you take too long (less than 30 seconds) to make a decision (click something, type in a field) on the login screen ? The screen goes black and everything reloads. Is this a feature or a sign something is wrong with the Chromebook ?

Comment: Also let me know if there is a better stack exchange for this question. This one was the top search result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is no it shouldn't and that it is not normal behavior.

A better place to ask this question is not on stack exchange but the Chrome OS support forum: https://support.google.com/chrome/community/?hl=en&gpf=%23!forum%2Fchrome